# Syntax highlighting in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, multiplatform

I want to highlight the syntax of the code block . The container has a text widget whose text is a variable.

I used `flutter_highlighter`  package but I don't want to specify the language every time I use it, I want it auto detected

`any_syntax_highlighter` was good but doesn't take variable as a input text, here I need to hardcode the text.